# Sharing a (windows/SMB) printer from one network to another

Tags: networking, linux-networking, samba, printing

I have two networks (A and B), which are effectively isolated from each other. Both networks use different AD domains. I have a printer, connected to a Windows (AD-joined) print server on network A, and I want to allow devices on network B to be able to print to it. If I connect a computer with  a NIC on either network, what do I need in order to be able to print from network B to network A? The 'bridge' computer will ideally be running Ubuntu server. Is this possible to achieve purely at the network level (port-forwarding/NAT), or do I need to use Samba? If so, how do I do this, ensuring that the user credentials to access the print server originate from the client (on network B) and not from the 'bridge'?

Answer (score 0):

A printer can be shared from two different print servers. Just have a Print Server in Domain B also connect to that printer and share it to Domain B clients. Without a trust between the two domains, doing it all from one print server is more trouble than it's worth as it will either require unauthenticated access or duplicate accounts.

Comment: Needs to go through the one print server for accounting purposes. We have something working currently with a Windows print bridge that 're-shares' the printer, but I'd prefer to use Linux if possible.